# Can't install game through apk and obb file

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, apk

I can't install a game through apk and obb file in my Android 6.0 Marshmallow. I have Samsung Grand Prime Plus and I have recently tried rooting my device several times but it failed. I'm wondering if it might somehow be relevant to this problem.

I installed the apk file, put the obb file in the respective folder and the game looks like it's been installed, but gets stuck on the startup screen. I think it's not picking up the obb file since the startup screen is probably part of the apk file. I have tried this with both the internal and external memories. I'm sorry for the awkward terminology. I'm new to this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

- Accept/Check the App Permission
- Check if you Place the obb file to android/obb
- Check if the App is Compatible with your Phone